# Peak detection in python with scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a numpy array, called det1, which is a signal with many peaks. I would like to detect peaks(local max) and save the values.

I am trying this:

```
from scipy.signal import find_peaks_cwt
from scipy import signal
peakind = signal.find_peaks_cwt(det1, np.arange(1000,2000))
```

and i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mobility.py", line 49, in <module>
    peakind = signal.find_peaks_cwt(det1, np.arange(1000,2000))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/signal/_peak_finding.py", line 514, in find_peaks_cwt
    cwt_dat = cwt(vector, wavelet, widths)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/signal/wavelets.py", line 357, in cwt
    output = np.zeros([len(widths), len(data)])
MemoryError
```

what am i doing wrong? Could you suggest a better way to detect the peaks?

Comment: You are likely exceeding the memory your computer has available (are you using 64 or 32 bit Python?). What is the shape of `det1`?

Comment: Than you very much for your response. I am using 64 bit Python.  det1.shape gives 
(20510000,)

Comment: 20 Billion anything is likely to get you a `MemoryError`.  Reduce the number of `width`s you are using.

Comment: Well the `output` is being built with `len(widhts) = 1000` (np.arange) and `len(data) = 20 510 000`. So over 20 billion cells which seems your computer can't handle.